# How can this script be improved (hangman game)?

Tags: python

Here is the code. I am getting some errors when I run it in my terminal. If you can look through and let me know if you see any errors or any input at all would be appreciated.

```
import random

name = input("What is your name? ")
print ("Hello, " + name, "Let's play hangman!")
print("Try to guess the word in 8 tries or less")

def hangman()

welcomeScreen()
word = random.choice(["hello", "goodbye", "dogs", "computer"])

validLetters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

turns = 8
guessed = ''

while len(word) > 0:
msg = ""
missed = 0
for letter in word:
    if letter in guessed:
        msg = msg + letter
    else:
        msg = msg + "_" + "  "
        missed += 1

if msg == word:
    print(msg)
    print("correct!, the word is: ", word)

print("Guess the word:", msg)

guess = input()

if guess in validLetters:
        guessed = guessed + guess
else:
    print("enter another letter: ")
    guess = input()

if guess not in word:   
    turns = turns - 1 
    if turns == 8:
        print("  o")
    if turns == 7:
        print("  o")
        print("  |")
    if turns == 6:
        print("  o")
        print("  |")
        print(" / ")
    if turns == 5:
        print("  o")
        print("  |")
        print(" / \ ")
    if turns == 4:
        print("  o")
        print("  |-")
        print(" / \ ")
    if turns == 3:
        print("  o")
        print(" -|-")
        print(" / \ ")
    if turns == 2: 
        print("  o")
        print(" -|-")
        print("_/ \_")
    if turns == 1:
        print("you did not guess correctly!:",word)

welcomeScreen()
```

I am getting some errors when it comes to defining hangman and word. Ex. def hangman() is an invalid syntax.

Comment: what error do you get? add the error msg as well. give us all the information you get.

Comment: General hints: (1) Understand local and global variables. (2) Define things before you use them. (3) Care about spelling.

Answer (score 1):

You have in total 3 errors.

**1. Define function before execution.**

You have to define your function before you execute it. So the `hangman()` has to be after `def hangman():` or you put it in a function as well and call it at the end of the script.

**2. indent**

you have to be careful about the correct indent. The while and after that are not correctly indent. So the code with while and after that is not in the function hangman() at all and so it doesn't know the variable word.

**3. typo**

you have a typo in validLetters / validLeters.

Comment: It also doesn't terminate correctly (starts with `msg = " "` not the empty string `""`.

Comment: True, I only looked at the error not at the logic of the code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Boendal answer, I just played the game, but nothing happens when I guess all the letters correctly :/ Add another if statement to show a victory message and exit the game.

**Update**

I can see you alredy have if statement for victory but it never executes because of these 2 reasons:

```
if msg == word:
    print(msg)
    print("correct!, the word is: ", word)
    break
```

your if statement is comparing the wrong variables. `msg` variable holds the guessed word with undercores. e,g `c_o_m_p_u_t_e_r`. Instead, you want to compare the variable `guessed` with the variable `word`.

```
if guess in validLetters:
    guessed = guessed + guess
```

You don't want to add wrong guessed letters to the variable `guessed` so add another condition which will only execute the if statement if the guessed letter is correct

`if guess in validLetters and guess in word:`